# stop faces message being added again in restore view

Tags: jsf-2, postconstruct

I add some faces message in the post construct.
but when there is navigation from the current page the postconstruct is called again  during restore view phase and adds the faces message again.

is there a way to prevent the faces message from being added during restore phase?

I can check the phase id and not add the message.

but is that the right way ? is there any other way?

Comment: Why exactly are you adding a faces message in the post construct in the first place?

Comment: i am trying to load something from the database. and when it fails or something is not met .i want to show a error message.

Comment: Okay. Why exactly are you navigating using a POST request (via command link/button with `action`) instead of using a normal GET request (via regular link/button with `outcome`)?

Comment: here is my scenario.
1) user Login - sees user info page.
2)cicks next button - sees company page.
show error message (Say the company is bankrupt).
clicks prev - should come to user info page.
the error message from init is shown on userinfo page too.

i hope u get an idea.